# Is there a way to clean up this structure?

Tags: python, data-structures

I am practicing programming and was wondering if there is a way to improve my nesting as I go. I understand this structure will never be used in serious projects, but are there ways to improve how I structure this?

```
Johnny = {
    'first': 'john',
    'last': 'doe',
    'age': '20',
    'location': 'new york city',
}

Bob = {
    'first': 'robert',
    'last': 'johnson',
    'age': '28',
    'location': 'san francisco',
}

Jenny = {
    'first': 'jennifer',
    'last': 'lopez',
    'age': '40',
    'location': 'miami',
}

people = [Johnny, Bob, Jenny]

for name in people:
    print('This is ' + name['first'].title() + ' ' + name['last'].title() +
          '. They moved to ' + name['location'].title() + ' when they were ' + name['age'] + ' years old.')
```

Comment: I don't see any down sides to the structure. Did you have any specific concerns?

Comment: Make it a class or namedtuple to ensure that there are the same entries for all instances. Also, it would probably make sense to make `age` an `int`.

Comment: General design is a complex domain and best choices often depends on the context. For a simple script that will be used once, simple maps are generally the best choice. If this is intented to be part of a larger project, it will make sense to encapsulate people data inside a class and provide methods to handle it. I am sorry, but outside of context, this is too broad for SO.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you need input on? Are you wondering whether your ``dict``s are fine? Are you wondering whether you should use ``dict``s at all? Are you wondering whether your ``people`` list is okay? Whether you should have separate people outside of the ``people`` list?

Comment: Thank you all for the comments, my concern was how can I improve what I have going on currently, as I want to break any bad habits I might have early on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dicts are the same, you also can use python classes.
Here is an example:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, person_dict):
        self.person_dict = person_dict

    def get_person_data(self):
        return f'This is {self.person_dict["first"].title()} {self.person_dict["last"].title()}. ' \
            f'They moved to {self.person_dict["location"].title()} when they were {self.person_dict["age"]} years old.'


johnny = Person(Johnny)

print(johnny.get_person_data())
```

Output:

```
This is John Doe. They moved to New York City when they were 20 years old.
```

Answer (score 1):

Have one list of dictionaries instead of 3 separate dictionaries and one list :

```
 people = [
{   'nick' : 'Johnny',
    'first': 'john',
    'last': 'doe',
    'age': '20',
    'location': 'new york city',
},

{   'nick' : 'Bob',
    'first': 'robert',
    'last': 'johnson',
    'age': '28',
    'location': 'san francisco',
},
{   'nick': 'Jenny',
    'first': 'jennifer',
    'last': 'lopez',
    'age': '40',
    'location': 'miami',
}
]
```

Comment: Ah, this looks like it would be a bit faster, and looks cleaner. Would indexing go something like people[1][nick] ?

Comment: @dpowe3rd , yes but only if it is people[1]['nick']  , 'nick' is a key, not a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Make a class and then you can append to an array with the new object:

```
class human(object):
    def __init__(self, first='', last='', age=0, location='',nick=''):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.age = age
        self.location = location
        self.__name__ = nick
    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}{}'.format(self.__class__.__name__, self.first)

people = []
people.append(human(nick='Johnny',first='john',last='doe',age="20",location='new york city'))
people.append(human(nick='Bob',first='robert',last='johnson',age="28",location='san francisco'))
people.append(human(nick='Jenny',first='jennifer',last='lopez',age="40",location='miami'))

for name in people:
    print('This is ' + name.first.title() + ' ' + name.last.title() +
        '. They moved to ' + name.location.title() + ' when they were ' + name.age + ' years old.')
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea of changing a 'age' to an int, keeping that in mind will more than likely save me some trouble moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

Let's clean up the string interpolation.  Python has a number of ways of plugging values into a string that are cleaner than using addition to concatenate.

Newer versions of Python have f-strings that allow you to embed an expression like `name['first'].title()`.

```
In [1]: def output_string(name):
      :     return f"This is {name['first'].title()} {name['last'].title()}. They moved to {name['location'].title()} when they were {name['age']} yea
      : rs old."
      :
      :
      :

In [2]: [output_string(n) for n in people]
Out[2]:
['This is John Doe. They moved to New York City when they were 20 years old.',
 'This is Robert Johnson. They moved to San Francisco when they were 28 years old.',
 'This is Jennifer Lopez. They moved to Miami when they were 40 years old.']
```

You can also use the `format` method to insert a given keyword into a string, either explicitly with `kw = value` or by unpacking a dictionary with `**`.

```
In [3]: base_w_keys = "This is {first} {last}. They moved to {location} when they were {age} years old."

In [3]: base_w_keys.format(first = 'John', last = 'Doe', location = 'New York City', age = '20')
Out[3]: 'This is John Doe. They moved to New York City when they were 20 years old.'

In [4]: base_w_keys.format(**{'first':'John', 'last':'Doe', 'location':'New York City', 'age':'20'})
Out[4]: 'This is John Doe. They moved to New York City when they were 20 years old.'
```

Unfortunately, you can't include the `title` method directly, so we either need to preprocess the data.

```
In [5]: [base_w_keys.format(**{k:v.title() for k, v in d.items()}) for d in people]
Out[5]:
['This is John Doe. They moved to New York City when they were 20 years old.',
 'This is Robert Johnson. They moved to San Francisco when they were 28 years old.',
 'This is Jennifer Lopez. They moved to Miami when they were 40 years old.']
```